# Applying a style to an iOS custom renderer in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm developing a simple Xamarin.Forms app and I have created custom Entry renderers for Android and UWP.

I have successfully applied my own custom styles to the Entry renderers like so :

- For UWP

  ```
  protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
  {
      base.OnElementChanged(e);

      var customControl = e.NewElement;
      var nativeControl = new FormsTextBox();

      var style = Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Current.Resources["UserNameEntry"] as Windows.UI.Xaml.Style;
      nativeControl.Style = style;
      nativeControl.PlaceholderText = customControl.Placeholder;
      SetNativeControl(nativeControl);
  }
  ```
- For Android

  ```
  protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
  {
      base.OnElementChanged(e);
      if (e.OldElement == null)
      {
          var nativeEditText = (global::Android.Widget.EditText)Control;
          nativeEditText.SetBackground(Resources.GetDrawable("@drawable/username"));
      }
  }
  ```

So, it is dead simple to apply any custom style by using the native styling tools from Android and UWP platforms.

My question is, is there any way to do the same with iOS? How can I apply a style using a description-based file like a style.xaml in UWP or style.axml in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do for IOS like this :

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
                UIImage img = UIImage.FromFile("ImageName.png");
                Control.Background = img;      
            }
        }
```